# WebBrowser control invalid z-index rendering for <select> tag

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, internet-explorer, webbrowser-control

I have a WebBrowser control that loads web-page, targeted IE 9+. The problem is that this page is displayed normally in IE 9, 10, latest Firefox and Chrome, but when displaying in WebBrowser control, something goes wrong and drop-down appears over the calendar:

[image]

z-index of calendar is 1, for  tag it is not set (I also tried setting 0 explicitly - same result).

Page contains meta tag:

```
<meta content="IE=8,9" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"></meta>
```

so I excluded possibility of wrong compatibility mode of IE. In addition "Save" and "Close" buttons looks OK, so it is at least IE 9 mode (they look worse in IE 8 and 7).

Does anybody have an idea why the layout can be different in normal IE browser and WebBrowser control?

**UPDATE:** 
Issue only reproducing when the windows form with WebBrowser control is shown as a plugin of MS Word (2010). The same form, when run as a standalone application, is displayed as expected.

Comment: webbrowser control is stuck in IE 7 rendering mode by default you need to add a registrykey like in this article explains - http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/May/21/Web-Browser-Control-Specifying-the-IE-Version

Comment: @terrybozzio, that doesn't help unfortunately. If browser mode was IE7, it wouldn't display Save button in blue color.

Comment: Check DOM `document.documentMode` and `document.compatMode`. They should be something like these: document.documentMode: 9, document.compatMode: CSS1Compat, if `FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION` works correctly.

Comment: @Noseratio, yes, it works as you described. Displays documentMode=9 and compatMode=CSS1Compat. It looks like the problem isn't in CSS or compatibility. It is the problem of just drop-down list. It always appears on top. I've read that it is implemented as separate window in IE, so it differs from all other controls. But I have no idea why it looks different in standalone browser and in the WebBrowser control.

Comment: @OleksandrPshenychnyy, there's a bunch of [other features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330733(v=vs.85).aspx). E.g., try [FEATURE_GPU_RENDERING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330731(v=vs.85).aspx#gpu_rendering).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue appeared to be in the feature called 'FEATURE_USE_WINDOWEDSELECTCONTROL' (registry node 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_USE_WINDOWEDSELECTCONTROL'). It was enabled for WinWord.exe by default. Removing registry value 'WinWord.exe' fixed the problem.

I suppose it is a direct answer to the original question. But I'm not sure it is safe to remove this node from registry and how it can affect other applications and MS Word functionality.

[It is said](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927377/en) that non-windowed select control came to substitute the older (IE6-style) windowed control, but it had compatibility issues in IE7 with MS Office 2003 applications, so the registry setting 'FEATURE_USE_WINDOWEDSELECTCONTROL' was introduced to enable reverting this change. I didn't find any confirmation that that issues are not present in newer versions of MS Word, but from what I've found about possible issues and tested that - they are not reproduced (crashes when using select control with keyboard).

It is likely that I'll accept this solution and remove the setting FEATURE_USE_WINDOWEDSELECTCONTROL for MS Word 2010. If anybody knows the reason not to do this, please let me know.

Comment: If somebody interested, I decided not to take the risk of breaking 3rd party applications by deleting this setting for the whole MS Word application. Instead I extracted my UI into separate EXE and run it from MS Word as a separate process